# what is the correct coding of saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

Tags: c#

I want save data from textbox in particular path using savefileDialog.
I am trying this. It cannot save file on define path as define name.

```
 DialogResult sa = MessageBox.Show("Do you Want to save your doucument ?","SAVE",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (sa == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"; 
                    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Your File";
                    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
                    {
                        //what i do here...?
                    }

                    clear = true;
                }
                if (sa == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("OK... As you wish");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Er, trying not to be facetious but in the "what do I do here" you put the code to save your document - you'd do better to check the return result from the showdialog of the savefile  rather than just check filename isnt empty.

Comment: "what i do here...?" > You add the [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write text to a file.

Comment: Can you put here the exception you get if you get one? If not, can you detail more what does mean "It cannot save file on define path as define name"? What does mean "It cannot..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a warning on exit with unsaved content, I would skip the first dialog. Instead, you should check how the saving dialog was closed. Your code tries to save the file even if the user canceled the saving dialog.

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     // maybe with some error handling in a try-catch
     File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: its working when i add system.IO before File.WriteAllText  but dialog box show two times. when i run this coding.

Comment: Have you removed your `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` line? When not, it can be the reason of the double showing ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName,textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to save to a plain text file, You can use System.Io.File namespace

```
if (!File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName))

   {
        File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, textBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("You choose to save to a file....");
   }
```

rest of your code should works fine.

Comment: Can you define me what is the difference between File.WriteAllText and File.AppendAllText....?

Comment: 1. WriteAllText : Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 2. AppendAllText : Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx